# Failed to construct kafka producer with Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm doing a simple kafka example project with Springboot and I'm having the error where the producer don't create but the rest works well.

The errors that I have it seems that it threw a exception because the producer didn't create but isn't explains why and I don't know:

```
2019-06-05 14:45:21.733  INFO 5988 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2019-06-05 14:45:21.755 ERROR 5988 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer] with root cause

java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:306) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:302) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:370) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:289) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:318) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:305) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.getTheProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:446) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:193) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.kafka.KafkaSimpleController.post(KafkaSimpleController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Here its my kafka configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, SimpleModel> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SimpleModel> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

Here its the controller, the endpoint "/api/kafka":

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/kafka")
public class KafkaSimpleController {

    private KafkaTemplate<String, SimpleModel> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaSimpleController(KafkaTemplate<String, SimpleModel> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;

    }

    @PostMapping
    public void post(@RequestBody SimpleModel simpleModel) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("myTopic", simpleModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this bootstrap server is running `127.0.0.1:9092`? try providing the zookeeper

Comment: I don't know. I'm new on it. How I can check? How I do provide?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: I already test the kafka with the command line and all works. I created a topic, I sent a message and I saw this message in a consumer, so I don't know the reason that not works on Springboot.

Comment: try `localhost:9092` instead of `127.0.0.1:9092`

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: What version of spring-kafka are you using? Newer versions of spring kafka you can basically drop all the config beans and have it configured by configuration properties in you application.properties(yml) Are you running kafka in docker containers or are you running confluent setup locally, or other?

Comment: I'm running locally and the version of spring-kafka is 2.2.6.

Comment: What Java version do you use? Does it fail for you even without Spring Boot? With the `java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl` it looks like there is some security access to the class ctor...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Had a similar issue from my end I imported the wrong `JsonSerializer` class. Changed to this import `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;`
All worked well.

Comment: faced the same issue due to the wrong import of StringSerializer. It got worked for me after changing the import to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Comment: I have the correct import. But still issue does not resolve. any other checks ?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
@swetha I'd make sure all my imports in config class are of org.spingframework or org.apache.kafka (avoid others like fasterxml etc).

Answer (score 0):

Under **config** files for **kafkaConfiguration** , change the **import**.

the import should be : `import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;`

Answer (score 0):

@3barney's solution helped me! Intellij IDE gives you 2 options for a `JsonSerializer` class and I chose the wrong one! The correct import statement is -

```
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you forget to connect the jackson-databind dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if you cannot find the corresponding certificates (jks) either because the ssl.truststore.location is incorrect or for any other reason